# Foreground Drawable doesn't cover entire View

Tags: android, view, android-framelayout, colordrawable

I am using a `FrameLayout` with a `ColorDrawable` foreground. Most of the time it works fine, but occasionally the colour doesn't fill the entire `View`. It seems to remember the heights of other views.

Here is an example demonstrating the problem.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
    Random random = new Random();
    final List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        list.add(50 + random.nextInt(150));
    final Drawable blue = new ColorDrawable(Color.BLUE);
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(this, -1, list) {
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            FrameLayout frameLayout;
            TextView textView;
            if (convertView == null) {
                frameLayout = (FrameLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
                textView = new TextView(MyActivity.this);
                frameLayout.addView(textView);
            } else {
                frameLayout = (FrameLayout) convertView;
                textView = (TextView) frameLayout.getChildAt(0);
            }
            textView.setHeight(list.get(position));
            frameLayout.setForeground(blue);
            return frameLayout;
        }
    });
}
```

I think the only gaps between the blue blocks should be the `ListView` dividers, but occasionally you get larger gaps as shown below. Can anyone explain this?

[image]

Comment: why do you remove the TextView from the FrameLayout, just to re-instantiate and add it again to the FrameLayout?

Comment: @Blackbelt I've changed the question. It was a bit odd what I was doing before.